# How to generate an image based on text with given width and no padding in C#

Tags: c#, image, text, drawing

I want to save a given text as an image. The image should have a fixed width (`200px` in my example). Around the text there should be no spacing, padding or whatever. Regardless what text is entered, the width should not change, only the height of the text. This works. However, there is still white padding around the text and the text is truncated on the right side.

I have already tried to change `StringFormat.GenericTypographic` and also tried without `AntiAlias`, but I do not get it to work. Can anyone help me to get this working?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Font font = new Font("Arial", 1000, FontStyle.Regular);
        Image i = DrawText("TEST MY STRING", font, Color.Red, Color.White);
        i.Save("test.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }

    private Image DrawText(String text, Font font, Color textColor, Color backColor)
    {
        Image img = new Bitmap(1, 1);
        Graphics drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);
        drawing.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
        SizeF sz = drawing.MeasureString(text, font, 0, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

        img.Dispose();
        drawing.Dispose();

        /* Set maximum width of string. */
        int textWidth = 200;
        float sf = textWidth / sz.Width;
        int textHeight = (int)(sz.Height * sf);


        img = new Bitmap(textWidth, textHeight);
        drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);
        drawing.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
        drawing.Clear(backColor);

        drawing.ScaleTransform(sf, sf);
        drawing.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0, new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap | StringFormatFlags.NoClip));
        drawing.Save();


        drawing.Dispose();
        return img;
    }
```

Comment: Not anybody has an idea to get this working? Worked with fellow students on this issue, but it seems to impossible to write generic code to get rid of paddings. :-(